# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined - Cypress test in java application

Tags: cypress

Error appears when I am trying to type text in input using .type()

visit() and click() methods are working fine.

My application is written in Vaadin.
[image: cypress error]

code:

```
  describe('Intern test', () => {
    it('Create rfp', () => {

      cy.get('tbody').find('.v-textfield-v-textfield-login').type('randomuser')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you double check if - cy.get('tbody').find('.v-textfield-v-textfield-login') yielding single element ?

Comment: yes, there is only one element with that class

Comment: can you share page source for that  or snippet code for the same element ?

Comment: KaranSharma HTML pasted in description

Comment: i guess your cy.get('tbody').find('.v-textfield-v-textfield-login') part should be working fine . As soon as you start typing some DOM is changing .  is your webpage behaving like this ?? can you please confirm